# Cannot subscript a value of type [String] with an index of type [NSIndexPath] - prepareForSegue

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, nsindexpath

I'm trying to send multiple rows from a UITableView to another UITableView using prepareForSegue function.

When I just send one option to the 2nd UITableView, the app works perfectly, BUT when I'm choose multiple rows and send those to the second UITableView as a header (for example, if I click first in "a" row, then "d" row and then "c" row... the second UITableView just show me the row "c" as a header, not the other 2 rows), it gives an error.

Pic of the error:

[image]

These are the lines I wrote for the first UITableView:

```
let array = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e"]

@IBOutlet var initialTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    initialTableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "segueA" {
        if let destination = segue.destinationViewController as? Content {
            if let selectedRows = initialTableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
                destination.title = array[selectedRows]
            }
        }
    }
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.array.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellA", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cell.textLabel!.text = array[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath){
    let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)
    if (cell?.accessoryType == UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark) {
        cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.None
    } else {
        cell!.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryType.Checkmark
    }
}
```

The second view contains these lines:

```
var contentArray:[String] = []

@IBOutlet var contentTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    contentArray.append(title!)
}

func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return contentArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellContent = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellContent", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
    cellContent.textLabel!.text = "Second test"
    return cellContent
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    return contentArray[section]
}
```

So, if I wanna choose multiples rows and send these from the first to the second UITableView... how can I solve this error?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you want `destination.title` to be set to if they choose rows "a", "d", and "c"?

Comment: @vacawama if I choose rows "a", "d", "c" ... in the next UITableView I can see these options but as a headers. Actually it works with one option, but idk why when I'm trying to include more sections(headers) it gives an error.

Comment: Your problem is that `selectedRows` is an array of `NSIndexPath`s.  You can't use that to index into your array.  It sounds like you need to pass an array of strings to your second view controller instead of just setting a single string? Is that correct?

Comment: @vacawama exacty! I wanna send an array of strings to the 2nd view (I edit the question including the codes of the 2nd UITableView)

Comment: @vacawama so.. Instead of put `destination.title = array[selectedRows]` you said just to put `selectedRows` ?

Comment: Where (and how) is `title` declared in the destination view?

Comment: @vadian i created a UITableViewCell (the cell inside the 2nd UITableView is customized) and here is included the "title": `@IBOutlet var headTitle: UILabel! 
func configCell(title:String) { headTitle.text = title }` ..... do you think the problem is there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that `selectedRows` is an array of `NSIndexPath`s. You can't use that to index into your array. You need to pass an array of `String`s to your second view controller instead of just setting a single string.

Use `map` to select the strings from `array` to pass to the `contentArray` property of the destination viewController:

```
destination.contentArray = selectedRows.map { array[$0.row] }
```

You'll need to decide a new sensible setting for `destination.title`.

You'll want to remove this line from `viewDidLoad`:

```
contentArray.append(title!)
```

Comment: yea! you're right!! now gives me an error in `contentArray.append(title!)` Error type: **"Thread 1: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)"** .... btw, great explanation

Comment: That's because `title` is `nil`.